# Blow-up, Exercise 22.2.A, Vakil.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, blowup

Vakil (FOAG) defines the blow-up $X \hookrightarrow Y$ (closed subscheme corresponding to a finite type quasicoherent sheaf of ideals) to be Cartesian diagram

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
E_X Y @>>> Bl_X Y\\
@VVV @VV{\beta}V \\
X @>>> Y
\end{CD}$$

such that $E_XY$ (the scheme-theoretic pullback of $X$ by $\beta$) is an effective Cartier
divisor on $Bl_XY$, such that any other such Cartesian diagram

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
D @>>> W\\
@VVV @VVV \\
X @>>> Y
\end{CD}$$

where $D$ is an effective Cartier divisor on $W$, factors uniquely through it:

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
D @>>> W\\
@VVV @VVV \\
E_X Y @>>> Bl_X Y \\
@VVV @VVV \\
X @>>> Y
\end{CD}$$

We call $Bl_XY$ the blow-up (of $Y$ along $X$, or of $Y$ with center $X$).

Next we have the exercise 22.2.A: If $U$ is an open subset of $Y$, then $Bl_{U\cap X}U \cong \beta^{-1}(U)$, where $\beta: Bl_XY\longrightarrow Y$ is the blow-up.

I think just note that the diagram

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
(E_X Y)\cap\beta^{-1}(U) @>>> \beta^{-1}(U)\\
@VVV @VV{\beta|_{\beta^{-1}(U)}}V \\
U\cap X @>>> U
\end{CD}$$

is the blow-up of $(U\cap X) \hookrightarrow U$. And it will be because $\beta|_{\beta^{-1}(U)}$ is the restriction of $U \subset Y$ in $\beta:Bl_{X}Y \longrightarrow Y$.

Is this right? Any tips on how to answer the exercise?

Comment: you have to check two things: First you have to check that pullback of $U\cap X$ is a carrier divisor which is true because it is restriction of  carrier divior $E_X Y$ to an open subset, second you have to check that it has universal property, for this use the universal property of blow up of $X$ to get a map to $W\to Bl_X Y$ and use cartesian diagrams to show that this map factor through $\beta^{-1}(U\cap X)$

Comment: I've swapped out your pictures for commutative diagrams. See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2324/how-to-draw-a-commutative-diagram) for more information on how to write commutative diagrams here on MSE.